# Why is the last tab active during page loading?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tabs

When I go to the page, for some reason the last tab is always active, but it is necessary that the first is active. I don’t understand why this is happening. It seems that if `i=0`  then the first is active, if not, then there is no attack, for some reason it always jumps to the last Please help

```
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

                                // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts

                                $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy ); ?>



                                <div class="category-title">

                                        <div class="container">

                                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

                                                        <?php

                                                        $i=0;

                                                        foreach( $terms as $term ) {

                                                                if($i==0){

                                                                ?>

                                                                    <li class="nav-item portfolio-item"><a class="nav-link  nav-link-portfolio active" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $term->slug ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo $term->slug ?>"><h5><?php echo $term->name ?></h5></a></li>

                                                                <?php } else { ?>

                                                                        <li class="nav-item portfolio-item"><a class="nav-link nav-link-portfolio" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $term->slug ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo $term->slug ?>"><h5><?php echo $term->name ?></h5></a></li>

                                                                <?php } ?>

                                                        <?php $i++; }; ?>

                                                </ul>

                                        </div>

                                </div>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                                <div class="tab-content">

                                    <?php



                                    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

                                        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );



                                        $i=0;

                                        foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>

                                                <?php

                                                $args = array(

                                                        'post_type' => $post_type,

                                                        'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts

                                                        'tax_query' => array(

                                                                array(

                                                                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,

                                                                        'field' => 'slug',

                                                                        'terms' => $term->slug,

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                );

                                                $posts = new WP_Query($args);

                                                ?>   <?php



                                                 if ($i==0){ ?>

                                                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" ><?php } else{ ?>

                                                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" >

                                                    <?php }
```

Comment: I don't see you increase $i in your code. If you don't increase it in foreach, your html code will add active class for all div. tag. Because it is always as 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function () {

      jQuery('#myTab a:last').tab('show');

 });
```

I had such a function. I forgot to remove, so I showed the last tab